# Using two threads and system() command to run shell scripts: how to make sure that one shell script is started before another

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

There are two shell scripts:

```
#shell_script_1
nc -l -p 2234
```

---

```
#shell_script_2
echo "hello" | nc -p 1234 localhost 2234 -w0
```

---

From inside the C++ program, I want to run shell script no.1 first, and then run shell script no.2. What I have now is something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  std::string sh_1 = "./shell_script_1";
  std::string sh_2 = "./shell_script_2";

  std::thread t1( &system, sh_1.c_str() );

  usleep( 5000000 ); //wait for 5 seconds

  std::thread t2( &system, sh_2.c_str() );

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

}
```

When I run the program above, shell_script_1 runs before shell_script_2, as expected. However, is a 5-second wait enough to make sure that the two shell scripts start in order? Is there anyway I can enforce the order other than set a timer and cross my finger? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to "start" the first script before the second.  You want the first script to actually be listening on the port you've specified.  To make that happen, you need to check periodically.  This will be platform dependant, but on Linux you could check `/proc/PID` of the first child to know what file descriptors it has open, and/or run `nc -z` to check if the port is listening.

A simpler approach would be to automatically retry the second script a few times if it fails to connect and the first thread is still running.

A more sophisticated approach would be make your C++ program bind two ports and listen on both, and change your first script to connect instead of listen.  This way both scripts would act as clients, and your C++ launcher would act as the server (even if all it does is pass the data between the two children), giving you more control and avoiding a race.

Comment: The more sophisticated approach presented is definitely cleaner in several ways, but the second, "simpler" approach is the best model for how a client and server running on different machines would orchestrate things.